# Power Bi - how to export to excel by another user

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I am having problem with exporting a table from Power BI. I have a simple report - three tabs, in each a table from the same source, very similiar to each other. When the report is published and shared with other users only the table from the second tab give the possibility to import to excel. So when I hover over the report the menu on the right side pops out and I can select the export option. On the two other table from other table the menu doesn't pop out, so no way to export or do othe action from the menu. I spent hours on looking on the properties of the tables but could find the solution. Maybe you have a clue where I can switch the popup menu?

Thanks in advance